# Groovy: comparing `"8" > 16` works and `"16" > 16` throws ClassCastException exception

Tags: groovy, string-comparison

I execute following expression in Groovy shell:

> groovy:000> '8' > 16
>
> ===> true

But when execute expression like:

> groovy:000> '16' > 16

it throws following exception:

> ERROR java.lang.ClassCastException:
>
> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

In case of `'8' > 16`, I think it is `'8' > '16'`, so it compares dictionary order of two strings. Why it cannot convert `16` to `'16'`? What does this exception mean?

My groovy version is:

`Groovy Version: 2.4.8 JVM: 1.7.0_80 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy adds via [`DefaultGroovyMethods`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.8/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#compareTo-java.lang.Character-java.lang.Number-) a custom [`compareTo()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.8/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#compareTo-java.lang.Character-java.lang.Number-) methods to `Character` and `Number` classes that allows you to compare character's ASCII ordinal number against a number value. It means that when you execute:

```
'z' > 12
```

in a Groovy Shell, compiler calls:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.compareTo((char) 'z', 12)
```

method instead, because a single character `String` is equivalent of `Character`. And similar thing happens when you execute:

```
12 > 'z'
```

Compiler sees it as:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.compareTo(12, (char) 'z')
```

However, when you execute expression like:

```
'16' > 16
```

following method gets executed:

```
'16'.compareTo(16) // String.compareTo(String other) <-- passing Integer value throws ClassCastException
```

It happens because `String` of size 2 (or more) is not an equivalent of a `Character`. This is why you get:

```
ERROR java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

because there is no method `String.compareTo(Number n)` and compiler does not cast `Number` directly to `String` in this case. It tries to execute `String.compareTo(String other)` method and passing a parameter with a different type than a `String` throws `ClassCastException` in this case.

If you cast `16` to `String` directly, compiler wont complain anymore:

```
'16' > (String) 16
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but the exception in `'16' > 16` is `cannot cast java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String` not `Cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'`

`

Comment: @ViciOs Yes, you're right, it was a different exception. I've updated the answer to show exactly what happens and which class is responsible for executing expression like `'8' > 16`